# React - Maximum Update Length Exceeded

Tags: reactjs, onclick

Does anyone know why

```
onClick={this.props.onPageChange("home")}
```

causes this error (maximum update length exceeded) but turning it into an arrow function:

```
onClick={() => this.props.onPageChange("home")}
```

fixes it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `onClick` expects a function, when you do this

```
onClick={this.props.onPageChange("home")}
```

you are passing the value that's returned from calling `onPageChange`. But doing this

```
onClick={() => this.props.onPageChange("home")}
```

actually passes a function to `onClick` and it works perfectly.